# Using a table to perform multiple REPLACE calls against a column

Tags: mysql, replace

I have a need to create a SQL solution to perform several search and replace operations on a string column.  The number of search/replace terms is dynamic as well as the search and replace terms themselves.

For this reason, I plan on using a table that contains all the search and replace terms needed.  So the basis setup involves two tables, a general table containing a string column with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE GENERAL_TABLE (
    ID           INTEGER NOT NULL
  , SOURCE_TEXT  VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL
  , CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

and a search and replace term table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE SEARCH_REPLACE (
    SEARCH_TERM   VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
  , REPLACE_TERM  VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
);
```

Is there a way replace all the `SEARCH_TERM` values found in each `SOURCE_TEXT` value with the corresponding `REPLACE_TERM` values?

As an example, if `GENERAL_TABLE` is populate with the following records:

```
ID  SOURCE_TEXT
--  -------------------------------------------------------
 1  honesty is the best policy.
 2  honesty is the best policy - when there is money in it.
 3  we are all worms. but i believe that i am a glow-worm.
 4  believe you can and you're halfway there.
 5  ambition must be made to counteract ambition.
 6  run, run as fast as you can.
```

and `SEARCH_REPLACE` is populated with the following records:

```
SEARCH_TERM  REPLACE_TERM
-----------  ------------
honesty      taco tuesday
policy       sale
money        cheese
worm         robot
believe      know
ambition     loans
run          swim
```

Then the desired results in the `GENERAL_TABLE` after all the searching and replacing are:

```
ID  SOURCE_TEXT
--  -----------------------------------------------------------
 1  taco tuesday is the best sale.
 2  taco tuesday is the best sale - when there is cheese in it.
 3  we are all robots. but i know that i am a glow-robot.
 4  know you can and you're halfway there.
 5  loans must be made to counteract loans.
 6  swim, swim as fast as you can.
```

This entire process is going to be carried out by a user with DBA like privileges.  So, any solution can make use of DDL commands if needed.

Comment: You will probably need to write your own function to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that utilizes a work table to store successive search/replace results.  The solution involves three SQL steps.  First create a table to do all the intermediate work where `SOURCE_TEXT` is the original `GENERAL_TABLE` value and `TARGET_TEXT` is the search/replace result for:

```
-- workspace table
-- all search/replace work is done in this table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS GENERAL_TABLE_WORK;
CREATE TABLE GENERAL_TABLE_WORK (
    ID           INTEGER NOT NULL
  , SOURCE_TEXT  VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL
  , TARGET_TEXT  VARCHAR(1024) NULL
  , LAST_ID      INTEGER NULL
  , REC_NUM      INTEGER
  , CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (ID, REC_NUM)
);
```

Next, join the `GENERAL_TABLE` with the `SEARCH_REPLACE` table and use that as a table to select all the search/replace results into the workspace table.  A control table is also used in the join to maintain state between successive search/replace results:

```
-- perform search/replace on source text
-- creating one record for each search/replace value
-- using the last replace results as the next input string
-- R is used solely to intialize variables
-- the ordering in A is crucial to maintain the correct variable state
INSERT INTO GENERAL_TABLE_WORK (
  SELECT
      A.ID AS ID
    , A.SOURCE_TEXT AS SOURCE_TEXT
    , CAST(IF(@lastid = A.ID,
       @text := REPLACE(@text, A.SEARCH_TERM, A.REPLACE_TERM),
       @text := REPLACE(A.SOURCE_TEXT, A.SEARCH_TERM, A.REPLACE_TERM)) AS CHAR)
       AS TARGET_TEXT
    , @lastid := A.ID AS LAST_ID
    , @record := @record + 1 AS REC_NUM
  FROM
    (SELECT G.ID AS ID, G.SOURCE_TEXT AS SOURCE_TEXT,
       S.SEARCH_TERM AS SEARCH_TERM, S.REPLACE_TERM AS REPLACE_TERM
       FROM GENERAL_TABLE G JOIN SEARCH_REPLACE S
       ORDER BY G.ID, S.SEARCH_TERM) A
    JOIN (SELECT @lastid := NULL, @text := NULL, @record := 0) R
);
```

Lastly, the `GENERAL_TABLE` values are replaced with the last search/replace result found in  `GENERAL_TABLE_WORK` for each original record:

```
-- copy target text back to original table
-- only taking the highest rec_num record for each id.
UPDATE GENERAL_TABLE G
  JOIN
    (SELECT W1.* FROM GENERAL_TABLE_WORK W1
     LEFT OUTER JOIN GENERAL_TABLE_WORK W2 ON (W1.ID = W2.ID AND W2.REC_NUM > W1.REC_NUM)
     WHERE W2.ID IS NULL
    ) A ON (G.ID = A.ID)
SET G.SOURCE_TEXT = A.TARGET_TEXT
WHERE NOT A.TARGET_TEXT = A.SOURCE_TEXT
;
```

Answer (score 0):

- Get all row value in SEARCH_Replace to a string variable + include the replace function

  Declare @str nvarchar(2000) 
  set @str  = 'Replace(SOURCE_TEXT,' 
  select top 1 @str = @str + ''''+SEARCH_TERM + ''',''' + REPLACE_TERM + ''')' from @SEARCH_REPLACE  --First row 
  select @str = 'Replace(' + @str + ',''' +SEARCH_TERM + ''',''' + REPLACE_TERM + ''')' from @SEARCH_REPLACE where SEARCH_TERM not like 'honesty' --the other rows
- build query for the @str

  declare @sql nvarchar(4000) 
  set @sql = 'select Source_Text, ' + @str + '  from GENERAL_TABLE '
- Execute @sql

  exec(@sql)
- Table Result

  NEW_TEXT
  ---------------------------------------------------------
  taco tuesday is the best sale.
  taco tuesday is the best sale - when there is cheese in it.
  we are all robots. but i know that i am a glow-robot.
  know you can and you're halfway there.
  loans must be made to counteract loans.
  swim, swim as fast as you can.

Comment: Opps i am using sql syntax for mssql. but you can use the concept. Build the @sql string in the programming language, run it and you get the result. Hope that's help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try an update with select

```
UPDATE GENERAL_TABLE dest,
    (SELECT 
        SEARCH_TERM, REPLACE_TERM
    FROM
        SEARCH_REPLACE) src 
SET 
    dest.SOURCE_TEXT = REPLACE(dest.SOURCE_TEXT,
        src.SEARCH_TERM,
        src.REPLACE_TERM)
```

Cheers

Comment: This does not work as it results in only records 1 and 2 being changed.